# Enable machene joind to AAD to require two factor for login?

Tags: azure, entra-id

I have a bunch of machines configured in Azure that use AAD to login. As they currently only require Username and Password I feel that they are at risk. If a user logs in on the web then they are prompted for two factor, but not if they login with the same account to a desktop.

**How do I require two factor for RDP/terminal login to any computer joined to my AAD domain?**

Just to be clear:

- I have no on-premises Active Directory (and don't want)
- I have no on-premises infrastructure (and don't want)

Answer (score -1):

You can't. Azure Cloud MFA is only available for Office 365, Azure Portal Administration and Cloud Applications.

[Available versions of Azure Multi-Factor Authentication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/multi-factor-authentication/#available-versions-of-azure-multi-factor-authentication)

You can, however, install the Azure On-premises MFA Server and use an RD Gateway to accomplish this. RD Gateway is necessary for Windows Server 2012 R2 and later.

[Remote Desktop Gateway and Azure Multi-Factor Authentication Server using RADIUS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/multi-factor-authentication-get-started-server-rdg/)

For Windows Server 2012 and earlier:

[Windows Authentication and Azure Multi-Factor Authentication Server](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/multi-factor-authentication-get-started-server-windows/#to-secure-an-application-with-windows-authentication-use-the-following-procedure)

Comment: Since I have no on-premises infrastructure I have no interest in installing servers/